# Pro Tools: How can I move the sound within a region?

Tags: pro-tools

**Is there a way to move the sound/wave of a region (the sound is longer than the region), but keep the region bounds and fades untouched in Pro Tools?**

Example:

Before:

```
            |------------region--------------|
  SOUND-SOUND-SOUND-SOUNDSOUND-SOUNDSOUND-SOUNDSOUND
```

After:

```
            |------------region--------------|
            SOUND-SOUND-SOUND-SOUNDSOUND-SOUNDSOUND-SOUNDSOUND
```